# OS X: equivalent of Linux's wget

Tags: macos, shell, unix, http-get

How can I do an HTTP GET from a Un*x shell script on a stock OS X system? (installing third-party software is not an option, for this has to run on a lot of different systems which I don't have control on).

For example if I start the Mercurial server locally doing a *hg serve*:

```
... $ hg serve
```

And then, from a Linux that has the *wget* command I do a wget:

```
... $  wget http://127.0.0.1:8000
--2010-12-31 22:18:25--  http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 Script output follows
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `index.html
```

And on the terminal in which I launched the *"hg serve"* command, I can indeed see that an HTTP GET made its way:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Dec/2010 22:18:17] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 -
```

So on Linux one way to do an HTTP GET from a shell script is to use *wget* (if that command is installed of course).

What other ways are there to do the equivalent of a *wget*?  I'm looking, in particular, for something that would work on stock OS X installs.

Comment: Also convenient: http://mikebeach.org/2012/09/29/how-to-install-wget-in-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 909, accepted):

The following native command will work:

`curl http://127.0.0.1:8000 -o outfile`

Note that `curl` does not follow redirects by default. To tell it to do so, add `-L` to the argument list.

Comment: Also, *wget* is available via both [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) and [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/).

Comment: I came here from a Google search on how to get wget on Mac, so despite the OP's requirement to avoid installation of 3rd party software, I'll provide a link to a quick guide I found on [how to install wget without using MacPorts](http://osxdaily.com/2012/05/22/install-wget-mac-os-x/) for future reference.

Comment: It's also available on Homebrew.

Comment: Can I resume downloads using this?

Comment: Doesn't seem to follow forwards.

Comment: For downloading files you can use `-O` or `--remote-name` flag to auto rename downloaded file. e.g. `curl -O http://somehost.org/file.zip`

Comment: I have thought about aliasing `wget` to `curl -O` on my mac's, but this would be evil because it wouldn't be "real" wget. So I don't do that, and use my brain to remember `curl -O`.

Comment: You might want to use `curl -LO`, because `wget` follows redirects.

Comment: Remember to use -L to avoid [this problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321710/why-wont-curl-download-this-link-when-a-browser-will)

Answer (score 600):

`brew install wget`

[Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) is a package manager for OSX analogous to yum, apt-get, choco, emerge, etc.  Be aware that you will also need to install Xcode and the Command Line Tools.  Virtually anyone who uses the command line in OSX will want to install these things anyway.

If you can't or don't want to use homebrew, you could also:

Install wget manually:

```
curl -# "http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-1.17.1.tar.xz" -o "wget.tar.xz"
tar xf wget.tar.xz
cd wget-1.17.1
./configure --with-ssl=openssl -with-libssl-prefix=/usr/local/ssl && make -j8 && make install
```

Or, use a bash alias:

```
function _wget() { curl "${1}" -o $(basename "${1}") ; };
alias wget='_wget'
```

Comment: You might take a moment to explain homebrew, but it's important that there be a newbie-visible `wget` answer here since the only other one was deleted by it's owner, and `curl` is an alternative rather than a literal equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful to me as someone with brew already installed.

Comment: @Michaelangelo And that is not your job to vandalize others' posts. You should not be editing other answers to make your own points - that's inappropriate. In fact, the actions are being discussed on Meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315892/should-i-rollback-an-edit-that-i-reviewed-and-rejected

Comment: @EricHartford Down-voting doesn't solve the problem. It provided *one* alternative, without listing the **other** option of how to manually install wget.

Comment: I think you have a good point.  And I will edit the answer to incorporate your ideas.

Comment: fixed by updating to version 1.17.1

Comment: that wget alias is really cool!

Answer (score 110):

Curl has a mode that is almost equivalent to the default wget.

```
curl -O <url>
```

This works just like

```
wget <url>
```

And, if you like, you can add this to your .bashrc:

```
alias wget='curl -O'
```

It's not 100% compatible, but it works for the most common wget usage (IMO)

Comment: how do u do recursive with this?

Comment: You can use bash to add this into a loop like this: `for i in \`seq 1 <n>\` do curl -O <url>;done;` where <n> is the number of times you want to iterate and <url> is the url to pull.

Comment: Sometimes you'll need to add the `-L` flag to follow location redirects. You can use `curl -OL <url>` to do that.

Comment: `-O` also only applies to the next argument, so to download multiple URLs you have to use something like `curl -O "$url1" -O "$url2"` or `printf %s\\n "$url1" "$url2"|xargs -n1 curl -O`.

Answer (score 45):

1) on your mac type

```
nano /usr/bin/wget
```

2) paste the following in

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -L $1 -o $2
```

3) close then make it executable

```
chmod 777 /usr/bin/wget
```

That's it.

Comment: Better than an alias.

Comment: Almost correct. I believe that step one should be `vim /usr/bin/wget` though ;) haha just kidding. thanks for the answer -- this never really occurred to me and for some reason I don't feel like installing brew/fink/whatever, so kudos for the easy portable answer.

Comment: `-L` is important for handling http `301` responses.  wget handles them by default.

Comment: "curl -L https://resource.url/tar.tar.gz -O tar.tar.gz" worked fine, thanks for this sole workable solution among others in this thread for my use case.

Comment: sudo nano /usr/bin/wget

Comment: wow. this answer taught me *way* more than I was hoping to get out of this question.. I've spiraled into a deep dive on shell scripting and what not for the past 6 hours... Thanks

Answer (score 19):

Use `curl`;

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8000 -o index.html
```

Answer (score 17):

Here's the Mac OS X equivalent of Linux's wget.

For Linux, for instance Ubuntu on an AWS instance, use:

```
wget http://example.com/textfile.txt
```

On a Mac, i.e. for local development, use this:

```
curl http://example.com/textfile.txt -o textfile.txt
```

The -o parameter is required on a Mac for output into a file instead of on screen. Specify a different target name for renaming the downloaded file.

Use *capital* -O for renaming with wget. Lowercase -o will specify output file for transfer log.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of going with equivalent, you can try "brew install wget" and use wget.

You need to have brew installed in your mac.

Comment: Not gonna downvote, but this is a dupe of Eric's answered Jun 13 '13.

Answer (score 5):

You can either build wget on the mac machine or use MacPorts to install it directly.

```
sudo port install wget
```

This would work like a charm, also you can update to the latest version as soon as it's available. Port is much more stable than brew, although has a lot less number of formula and ports.

You can install MacPorts from `https://www.macports.org/install.php` you can download the `.pkg` file and install it.

Comment: and how do you install port?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `curl` instead. It is installed by default into `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 2):

## wget Precompiled Mac Binary

For those looking for a quick wget install on Mac, check out Quentin Stafford-Fraser's precompiled binary here, which has been around for over a decade:

https://statusq.org/archives/2008/07/30/1954/
<sup><sub>MD5 for 2008 wget.zip: 24a35d499704eecedd09e0dd52175582</sub></sup>
<sup><sub>MD5 for 2005 wget.zip: c7b48ec3ff929d9bd28ddb87e1a76ffb</sub></sup>

No make/install/port/brew/curl junk. Just download, install, and run. Works with Mac OS X 10.3-10.12+.

Comment: Wget has 11 CVEs since 2008, https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-72/product_id-332/GNU-Wget.html , so use this advise on your own risk.